# Google API Get event - Not Found

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to to get event resource using the following api

> https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/eventId.

However, I am receiving 404 Not Found response, eventId is correct, I've checked it many times. Also, I've tried to call same method from their website (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) and still receiving same error. You can find the attached screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV2Do.png).

API Response Body :

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "message": "Not Found"
           

 }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 1):

`404 Not Found` means just that not found.

The [event.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) method takes a event id as a parameter.

The user you are authencation with needs to have permission to access that event your its going to return a 404 not found for that user.

Try doing an [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) first for the calendar to get a list of all valid events for that calendar if it also returns a 404 then the problem would be that the user does not have access to that calendar.

Comment: I've tried to get events list and it is working properly, returned list of events

Comment: Then you just need to pass the event id from your list result to the event.get method

Comment: I did but keep receiving 404 not found

Comment: Can you include your code?